# Typical single branch git workflow

Tags: git

We are checking out git and would like to understand which workflow might suit our small team (4 developers).

Some details about what we do:

- We are working on a .NET product that is currently composed of 1
  repository with around 4-5 solutions, total of around ~ 70 projects
  and growing.
- We currently have 1 central repository with 1 branch.
- Each developer works on different code base areas, although
  occasionally will collaborate/modify other team member's code area.

What is a "typical" git workflow for a team such as ours?

I would like to spend as minimal time as needed on "administrative" operations as possible.

For example, today we have seen that a *git push* request by a developer fails since another push was made before, and he had to merge changes locally using *git pull* first.

Is a typical scenario going like this:

Developer, commit locally.
Pull from git repository.
Push into git repository.

Can we not skip the pull? (have the merge done on the remote server?)

Currentlly we are using ClearCase, and this is resolved by merging during the push ("commit") operation without the need to pull first.

Comment: pulls are mandatory since there may be conflicts to resolve. I suggest you divide your projects into submodules if you want to minimize the amount of potential conficts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, I would recommend at least two branches. We call ours `master` and `integration`. Master is the current stable production-ready code base. This is what's either in the customer's hand or about to be submitted to the App Store (we're an iOS shop). Integration is where we store our test-ready code. If someone asks for a test build, this is what we give them. Code here compiles and runs, but isn't perfect. Depending on your deployment and testing process you can have as many additional branches as you need. Branches in git are easy and fast, there's no reason to not have as many as you need.

Here's how our process works:

1. Developer uses `git pull` to get the latest version of integration on their machine.
2. Create a topic branch off of integration. 'git checkout -b fix-home-page` will create a new branch named "fix-home-page".
3. Fix fix fix, code code code make a new commit every 5 minutes because commits in git are easy and fast. Once you're done with your feature / bug fix:
4. Switch back to the integration branch and use `git pull` to make sure you've got the latest commit.
5. `git merge --squash fix-home-page` will pull in your branch in one nice clean commit and keep your history linear.
6. `git push` to shove your fixes back up to the main repo.

I like `git merge --squash` because it greatly reduces the number of conflicts. Other people like to use `rebase`, which will also give you a linear history and preserve all the commits from your topic branch. Use whatever suits you.

Finally, to answer your question: Yes, you have to do a git pull before pushing. Git is great about resolving conflicts, but if it can't resolve the conflict then you need human intervention to figure out what should be happening.

Comment: Does it resolve *some* conflicts when pushing, or *ALL* conflicts are needed to be resolved locally and then pushed? Also, do you checkout the new branch on the same work dir, or create a new folder for each branch you're working on? i am wondering how hard/easy it is to keep track on which branch you're currently working on.

Comment: Git resolves *no* conflicts when pushing. If the remote repo and your local repo have diverged, you'll have to pull before you push.

Comment: Git doesn't use folders for branching like SVN does. All checkouts will happen in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we not skip the pull? (have the merge done on the remote server?)

No. A merge could potentially result in a conflict, while you'll have to resolve manually -- thus, you have to update your local repository before pushing new changes, if another developer pushed changes since your last update.

Answer (score 0):

No, git has no idea what will happen with a merge - there could be conflicts - and it would need them to be merged by you before pushing.

Also, it is not advisable to have many projects in one git repository like you would in SVN. Git repos are very lightweight and you can have individual projects or a group of them, in different repos. This also ensures that people working on one project do not have to clone the entire repo and also there will be less need to "pull" and then push.

Comment: How can i have the same project or multiple projects' source code appearing in more than 1 repo? when a developer fixes something, where does he push the code? the code in other repos will become obsolete then.

Comment: @markmnl - facebook does too. Most of us aren't Google or Facebook though. Facebook does lot of work to get mercurial working efficiently - https://code.facebook.com/posts/218678814984400/scaling-mercurial-at-facebook/